# Why do sidebar folders turn white?

Tags: macos, color, sidebar

Sometimes, not always, when I drag a file to a sidebar folder, it turns white.  The folder I'm dragging into turns white, and it doesn't turn back.
  I have to delete the folder from the sidebar, and then re-import it, and then it's a normal color.

Comment: I encountered the same issue of only 1 sidebar folder turning white, but not when I was dragging it to sidebar. IT was there since I created the file a few months back. I am surprised one of the folders turned white, and my Dropbox started syncing!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why this happens, but you can go to **Finder > Preferences** and select the **Sidebar** tab. At the very bottom of the window will be a "Recent Tags" option with a checkbox next to it. Uncheck the box and it's fixed.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me.  However, on the same preferences tab, untick the folder and then re-tick it will fix it.  The only problem was that the folder re-appeared at the bottom of my sidebar list in Finder and I had to drag it back into place.

Answer (score -1):

ignore it - the problem goes away on its own and the text returns to black

Comment: Would be nice to solve the problem though...